# SUM of a column when values equal set value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get the sum of a column where another columns values are equal to certain values, this is how I am working it now

```
SELECT [Date]= CONVERT(char(10), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 103), Items = SUM(NumberOfItems), WorkstationID 
FROM [DB].[DB].[dbo].[SortStatistics]
WHERE RecordedPeriod Between '06/23/17 01:00:00AM' and '06/23/17 23:59:00PM' AND WorkstationID = 'D11' 
GROUP BY WorkstationID
SELECT [Date]= CONVERT(char(10), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 103), Items = SUM(NumberOfItems), WorkstationID 
FROM [DB].[DB].[dbo].[SortStatistics]
WHERE RecordedPeriod Between '06/23/17 01:00:00AM' and '06/23/17 23:59:00PM' AND WorkstationID = 'D12' 
GROUP BY WorkstationID
SELECT [Date]= CONVERT(char(10), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 103), Items = SUM(NumberOfItems), WorkstationID 
FROM [DB].[DB].[dbo].[SortStatistics]
WHERE RecordedPeriod Between '06/23/17 01:00:00AM' and '06/23/17 23:59:00PM' AND WorkstationID = 'D13' 
GROUP BY WorkstationID
```

Here is my results

```
 Date       Items   WorkstationID
 26/06/2017 14886   D11

 Date       Items   WorkstationID
 26/06/2017 12973   D12

 Date       Items   WorkstationID
 26/06/2017 12124   D13
```

I would like to see this as results

```
 Date       Items   Sorter
 26/06/2017 39983   DUAL
```

Column data types are as follows

```
Items, INT
WorkstationID, Varchar(4)
```

Comment: What is the condition for DUAL to be printed?

Comment: I am just showing the location where the stats are coming from....Eric just answered the question below...Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear where you want `'DUAL'` to come from, but you can just use a single query:

```
SELECT [Date] = CONVERT(char(10), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 103),
       Items = SUM(NumberOfItems),
       'DUAL' as Sorter 
FROM [DB].[DB].[dbo].[SortStatistics]
WHERE RecordedPeriod >= '2017-06-23 01:00:00' AND
      RecordedPeriod <  '2017-06-24' AND
      WorkstationID IN ('D11', 'D12', 'D13')
```

Comment: Just wanted to add the DUAL...... I just got a error......  Incorrect syntax near ','.         Also just tried to    ('D11'+'D12'+'D13') and when I do this I get NULL for the result

Comment: Change last line to `WorkstationID IN ('D11', 'D12', 'D13')`